# ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение

Tags: python, django

> ```
>  ConnectionRefusedError at /accounts/signup/
>  [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение
>  Request Method:  POST
>  Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:1900/accounts/signup/
>  Django Version:  2.0.7
>  Exception Type:  ConnectionRefusedError
>  Exception Value: 
>  [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение
>  Exception Location:  C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socket.py in create_connection, line 713
>  Python Executable:   C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\MAIN\venv\Scripts\python.exe
>  Python Version:  3.6.5
>  Python Path: 
>  ['C:\\Users\\Admin\\PycharmProjects\\MAIN\\new_django',
>   'C:\\Users\\Admin\\PycharmProjects\\MAIN\\venv\\Scripts\\python36.zip',
>   'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\DLLs',
>   'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib',
>   'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36',
>   'C:\\Users\\Admin\\PycharmProjects\\MAIN\\venv',
>   'C:\\Users\\Admin\\PycharmProjects\\MAIN\\venv\\lib\\site-packages',
>   'C:\\Users\\Admin\\PycharmProjects\\MAIN\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-39.1.0-py3.6.egg']
> ```

settings.py

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


SECRET_KEY = 'XXX'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',

 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount',

 'news',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'new_django.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
 {
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': ['templates'],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
 },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'new_django.wsgi.application'



DATABASES = {
 'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
 }
}


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
 {
    'NAME': 
 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 
'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 
'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 
'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
},
]



LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

SITE_ID = 1



STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/static/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/MAIN/new_django/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = 'C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/MAIN/new_django/static/media/'


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
 'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGIN_URL ='/accounts/login/'
LOGIN_BACKEND ='django.core.mail.backends.stmp.EmailBackends'
```

Comment: Какое представление замаплено на /accounts/signup/ ?

Comment: В каком смысле ? в urls.py?

Comment: Да, в urls.py на каждый url назначено какое-то представление. Ошибка возникает именно в нём. Его код и стоит показать. Да и полный текст ошибки неплохо было бы добавить в вопрос.

Comment: Регистрация сделана с помощью специальной библиотеки django-allauth

Comment: Так что там вряд ли может быть ошибка

Answer (score 0):

Для работы django-allauth должны быть корректно указаны [настройки EMAIL_xxx](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#email-backend). Про это есть в [документации](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#when-i-sign-up-i-run-into-connectivity-errors-connection-refused-et-al).